# using docker on linux with squid proxy. -- ubuntu 20.04

Tags: docker, proxy

I have docker 20.10.21 installed from apt.   The machine is not directly connected to the internet so we rely on our squid proxy.

I have set up a daemon.json file:

```
rful011@secphires01:~$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
     "http-proxy": "http://squid.auckland.ac.nz:3128",
     "https-proxy": "http://squid.auckland.ac.nz:3128",
     "no-proxy": "*.auckland.ac.nz"
}
```

as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

starting dockerd gives:

```
rful011@secphires01:~$ sudo /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: no-proxy, http-proxy, https-proxy
```

Clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Docker 1.5? The docker shipped with Ubuntu is version 20.10.

Comment: my mistake -- I was looking at the version given by `apt show docker`.  docker -v gives 20.10.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 20.04 ships Docker in [version 20.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/docker.io).

According to [the documentatio](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#proxy-configuration)n you need at least 23.0 to configure the proxy this way:

> The daemon can be configured in three ways:
>
> - Using environment variables (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, and NO_PROXY).
> - Using the “http-proxy”, “https-proxy”, and “no-proxy” fields in the daemon configuration file (Docker Engine 23.0 or newer).
> - Using the --http-proxy, --https-proxy, and --no-proxy command-line options. (Docker Engine 23.0 or newer).

So you either need to install a newer Docker version or you need to use environment variables.

You can use `sudo systemctl edit docker` to create a systemd drop in and configure environment variables there.

Comment: I created a `/etc/default/docker' and then used `sudo systemctl edit docker` to add `EnvronmentFile` entry